# App Not Installed As Package Appears To Be Invalid error while installing apk to android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I take a error while installing apk ;

App not installed as package appears to be invalid.
Target api : 33
Device android version : 13
Unity version 2019.4.18

I attached android logcat logs
I need help so much [image]
[image]

Comment: You forgot to tell us how you have built the APK you are trying to install. Please tell use the commands you use. Also please do not post screen shots of text output like logs in a screen shot. Modern IDEs have the capability to simply copy the text to clipboard.